# Filter Dates from Dataframe RStudio

Tags: r, date

I have seen multiple ways to filter out dates from a column within a dataframe but the outcome is not coming out the way I want. I'm looking for a way to remove the dates from the original dataset

```
  market_name      order_count   date year month day frequency wk
1    Twin Cities           3 2016-11-28 2016    11  28    Weekly 48
2    Twin Cities          11 2016-12-05 2016    12  05    Weekly 49
3    Twin Cities          22 2016-12-12 2016    12  12    Weekly 50
4    Twin Cities          59 2016-12-19 2016    12  19    Weekly 51
5    Twin Cities          58 2016-12-26 2016    12  26    Weekly 52
```

My dataset has a date column and I want to remove dates based on a condition. I have tried

```
dates <- 
  as.POSIXct(c("2020-03-16", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-30", "2020-04-6", "2020-04-13", 
               "2020-04-20", "2020-04-27", "2021-05-04", "2021-05-11", "2021-05-18",
               "2021-05-25","2021-06-01","2021-06-08"))

`%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y) 

train_1 <- train %>%
  filter(date %notin% dates)
```

and also

```
train_1 <- train %>% subset(date >= '2020-04-15', date <= '2020-06-05' )
```

The subset function is actually removing the variables but keeping the observations.I also want to add the date column is in Date format based on the as.Date function

Comment: Can you share some sample data or at least show the structure (`str`) of the data?

Comment: I have the sample dataset in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need a function. Try:

```
train[!train$date %in% dates, ]
```

as for getting a date range between

```
train[train$date >= '2020-04-15' & date <= '2020-06-05', ]
```

Comment: This is still returning only the condition rows I want the other rows outside of the condition returned

Comment: Are u referring to `train[!train$date %in% dates, ]` or `train[train$date >= '2020-04-15' & date <= '2020-06-05', ]`?

Comment: train[!train$date %in% dates, ]

Comment: for the record `train[!train$date %in% dates, ] ` return records which are not in the vector `dates`. Does this get what you expected?

Comment: So Im trying to filter out the returned records. So lets say the dataset has 6500 rows and the returned  condition has 500 rows I want a new dataset that has 6000 rows

Comment: `train[!train$date %in% dates, ]` gets you this, assuming `train$date %in% dates` is your `condition`
Would you be able to produce a re-producible data set and expected result?

Comment: When I run train[!train$date %in% dates, ] it is returning the same amount of observations as the original dataset

Comment: run `class(train$date` and `class(dates)`. Make sure they are of the same class

Comment: wowwwww Im clearly not smart thank you it worked

Comment: nw. Glad could help

Answer (score 0):

This is a common need in working with data. In addition to the above options, I like using between:

```
train_1 <- train %>%
  filter(between(date, as.Date("2020-04-15"), as.Date("2020-06-05")))
```